# Typescript: How to initialise a class property outside constructor

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a scenario where I need to initialize a class property outside the constructor. Consider the following example.

```js
class A {
    public prop: MyPropType;
    public id: string;

    public constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public init(value: string): void {
        this.prop = new MyPropType(value);
    }

    public toString(): string {
        return `${this.id} - ${this.prop.toString()}`;
    }
}
```

In above scenario I got error:

```
TS2564: Property ‘ prop’ has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
```

And if I make that property optional `prop?: MyPropType` then it starts complaining about its usage.

```
TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Both errors are quite understandable. I am looking for the right way and approach in Typescript to come around such a scenario.

Should we use `as` at every usage e.g. `(this.prop as MyPropType).toString()`, or is there any other Typescript way?

And if we make assertions on the usage of the functions, why Typescript didn't recognize it?

```js
    public toString(): string {
        assert(this.prop, 'Object property is not initialized');

        return `${this.id} - ${this.prop.toString()}`;
    }
```

Is there any way Typescript recognizes the above scenario and feels ok with it?

Comment: What is the definition of `MyPropType` ?

Comment: Any custom class

Comment: You can put `!`  after this.prop to tell typescript that this will always be defined if that's the case.

Comment: That's a really nice solution but stricter by TSLint `TSLint: Forbidden non null assertion(no-non-null-assertion)`. The first answer to question describe how to get around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I end up solving above problem with following pattern without changing any configuration related to typescript or tslint.

```js
class A {
    private _prop?: MyPropType;
    public id: string;

    public constructor(id: string) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public init(value: string): void {
        this._prop = new MyPropType(value);
    }

    public get prop() : MyPropType {
        return this._prop as MyPropType;
    }

    public toString(): string {
        return `${this.id} - ${this.prop.toString()}`;
    }
}
```

With this approach value of `prop` is initialized outside constructor and still can access the prop in the code without any warning or linting error.

Answer (score 4):

You can turn off the `"strictPropertyInitialization"` in your tsconfig which states that all properties have to be initialized in the constructor or

use the [Non-null assertion operator / bang operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) e.g.

```
public prop!: MyPropType;
```

Comment: I can't change tsconfig settings in my project.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to initialize with undefined when declaring with casting it to any.

```
class Some {
  private value: string = undefined as any;

  public init(value: string) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```